# Hash table print and insert function

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am writing a hash table function and the data it has is from a text file. The text file has a four digit student ID and a name with embedded spaces. The problem is the insert function doesn't get the first line from the file. I run the program and when I test it, the first student from the file doesn't come up. I check the rest of the students name by inputting their ID's and they output their names. Also, it doesn't output the full name it gets from the file, just the first. If I look up chris campos from the file, I would type in its four digit ID, but only chris will be output not chris campos.

If you want to see the full code, I will edit the post, but I believe the error should be in the code I posted. I think the code is right, but I want to see if others can see the error or how I can improve it.

Also, I am curious, I am using chaining to handle collisions. How can I make the program output all the names in the bucket that have the same four digit ID. If two names have the same ID, how can I make the program output the two names when the user inputs the ID.

```
2301 Robb Arredondo 
5401 Chris Campos
6305 Yogi Bear
9108 Yoshi Man 
0310 John Du
1812 Maria Yu
4318 Power Ranger
7122 Bob Chan
8225 Will Boo
5324 Ghost Lee
0134 Mary Su 
2150 Jane Mary
1100 Gary Campos 
2305 Alan Kong 
3420 Bill Nye 
5608 Alex Garcia 
9112 Goku Nani 
6750 Paul Avalos 
1220 Jason Noni 
9005 Oscar Roger 
6550 Geo Qwerty
1112 Mini Me
2315 Garfield Beria
4201 Just Saying
```

Here is how my program gets the data from the file:

```
HashTable hashtable;
std::ifstream file("students.txt");
int option;
std::string studentID;
std::string studentName;
std::string line;

if (!file.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Error in opening file\n";
}
else
{
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        file >> studentID >> studentName;
        hashtable.Insert(studentID, studentName);
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Here is my insert function..

```
void HashTable::Insert(std::string ID, std::string name)
{
    int location = Hash(ID, tableSize);

    if (listofStudents[location]->m_idNum == "empty")
    {
        listofStudents[location]->m_idNum = ID;
        listofStudents[location]->m_Name = name;
    }
    else
    {

        Student* ptr = listofStudents[location];
        Student* newStudent = new Student;
        newStudent->m_Name = name;
        newStudent->m_idNum = ID;
        newStudent->next = NULL;

        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = newStudent;
    }

}
```

Here is my retrieve function...

```
void HashTable::Retrieve(std::string ID)
{
int location = Hash(ID, tableSize);
Student* ptr;

for (ptr = listofStudents[location]; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
{
    if (ptr->m_idNum == ID)
    {
        std::cout << "--------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Name of Student: " << ptr->m_Name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "---------------------\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No Student Found\n";
}
}
```

Here is my hash function if you want to see how the hashing technique is working.It converts a string to an int. The reason I am using a string is because I need to use a string for the assignment.

```
int HashTable::Hash(const std::string& key, int tablesize)
{
    int hashVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        hashVal =  37 * hashVal + key[i];
    }
    hashVal %= tablesize;

    if (hashVal < 0)
        hashVal += tablesize;

    return hashVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is here:

```
file >> studentID >> studentName;
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. I would suggest dumping `line` into a `std::stringstream` and then extracting the fields from that:

```
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::string ID;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;

    ss >> ID >> firstName >> lastName;
    hashtable.Insert(studentID, firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

Note that you are trying to dump the name into a single string, but in fact there are two fields (first and last name), so you need two variables. You can combine them after that into a single string.

P.S. Re the hash table, the STL hashmap implementation (`std::unordered_map`) is your friend.

Comment: I wish I can use the STL, but I can't in this scenario. Thanks for pointing out the error. I was told that fstream can read line by line in a file.

Comment: It still isn't getting the first name of the file. It gets every other name in the file except the first one.

Comment: You don't need `file >> studentID >> firstName >> lastName;`, just remove it entirely. The fields on the current line are extracted from `ss`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here:

```
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    file >> studentID >> studentName; // This only read the id and the first name
    hashtable.Insert(studentID, studentName);
}
```

You should try:

```
file >> studentID >> firstname >> lastname;
file.ignore(); // this will pass the EOL character
```

Comment: Wouldn't that ruin my insert implementation. Because I can only use two parameters for it and how would my insert function take in the lastname.

Comment: You could use peek() method: char x;  while ((file.peek()!='\n') && (file>>x))  studentname += x;